# Getting checkbox and corresponding textfield values to display in one line

Tags: php, html, css

i have a form that generate checkbox fields and textfield fields dynamically based on the what  number i want. here is the form and the fields generated

```
<?php
     $num = "6";
     $index = "0";
     echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' name='myform' method='post'>";
     echo "<table>";
     for($i= 0;$i<$num;$i++){
        echo "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='indexnum[]' value='".$index."'><input type='checkbox' name='mychecks[]' value='check".$i."'><input type='text' name='checktext[]' size='20'></td><tr>";
$index++;
     }
    echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $num = count($_POST['indexnum']);
     for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $index = $_POST['indexnum'];
        $checkvalues = $_POST['mychecks'];
        $textValue = $_POST['checktext'];
        echo $index[$i].".)".$checkvalues[$i]." coressponse ".$textValue[$i]."<br>";

}
}
?>
```

the problem is that i can't get the values of the textfield correctly but that of checked box is OK.
please can someone help me out of here.
want i want is that when a checkbox is checked and the corresponding text field value is entered. the two values should be in one line that is they should be display as one in one line.
thanks

Comment: It will help if you can show the current html output...

Comment: Your question makes little sense. The code you've posted generates this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uZz9H/. What do you want it to do that it doesn't do?

Comment: The title of your question says `corresponding textfield values to display in one line` but the question itself has nothing to do with how the fields display, but is about getting the values from the fields. (and -- 1995 called, they want their `<table>` layout back)

Answer (score 0):

You have to acces array fileds. So while holding your kind of solution:

```
...
$index = $_POST['indexnum'][$i];
$checkvalues = $_POST['mychecks'][$i];
$textValue = $_POST['checktext'][$i];
...
```

Solution with just 2 inputs:

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' name='myform' method='post'>
 <table>
  <?php

  $num = "6";

  for($i= 0;$i<$num;$i++)
  {
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='mychecks[<?php echo $i;?>]' value='1'>
    <input type='text' name='checktext[<?php echo $i;?>]' size='20'>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <?php            
  }  
  ?>    

  <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
<?php    

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $i = 1;

  foreach ($_POST["mychecks"] as $id=>$val)
  {
    echo ($i++).".)".$id." coressponse ".$_POST["checktext"][$id]."<br>";
  }    
}
?>
```